# Leer Archivo Java en tiempo real

Tags: java

El problema que me sucede es que necesito realizar una aplicación en java que lea un archivo de texto plano línea por línea mientras el archivo se va actualizando.

Explico un poco mejor, el archivo se va a estar actualizando constantemente y estará escribiendo líneas y líneas en cuestión de milisegundos, la aplicación que debo construir entre otras cosas deberá leer dichas líneas mientras van siendo creadas, línea creada en el archivo será línea leída por la aplicación y procesada.

Mi cuestión queridos lectores es la siguiente, En java, ¿Qué opciones existen para realizar la lectura del archivo en tiempo real (Sin impedir que puedan seguir escribiendo en el)? y ¿Cuál seria la mas optima?.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Este es un caso clásico de concurrencia, el problema del productor-consumidor (en este caso un proceso será el encargado de escribir en el archivo y otro proceso el encargado de leer). Existen diversos mecanismos para abordarlo: monitores, semáforos, etc. y no hay una más óptima que otra. Hay una gran cantidad de artículos en Internet respecto al tema del problema del productor-consumidor resueltos con los mecanismos indicados en java. Elige un mecanismo y si tienes problemas con la implementación, puedes preguntar nuevamente las dudas puntuales, con mucho gusto te ayudaremos.

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: lectura bloqueante (el proceso se queda en espera mientras no haya nada que leer) o no bloqueante (si no hay nada que leer sigue adelante por otro lado) Dependerá de lo que necesites

Comment: El caso es que la aplicación que escribe no es modificable, la aplicación que lee debería de leer sin interrumpir en ningún momento.